# JavaScript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

Tags: jquery, onsen-ui

When I execute my Javascript I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

And I don't know how do fix it and why that is shown.

I have objects inside an  array,

example:

```
AsukohaArray = [{"Punkt":[[58.1056],[23.2589]],
                    "name":"Haapsalu Raamat",
                    "PunktiID": 23}];
```

My code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='search']").keyup(function() {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchTerm, "i");
    var output = "<ul id='result'>";
    $.each(AsukohaArray, function(key, val) {
      //console.log(val.name);
      if ((val.name).search(myExp) != -1) {
        output += '<li>';
        output += val.name;
        output += '</li>';
      }
    });
    console.log(output);
    output += "</ul>";
    $('div#update').html(output);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<ons-page id="my-page">
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
            <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>

        <div class="center">Kaardi vaade</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div id="nupuriba">
    <input type="search" class="search-input" id="#search">
    </div>
    <div id="update"></div>
    <div id="map-canvas">
    </div>
</ons-page>
```

When I insert "Haapsalu" then results are:

Haapsalu piiskopilinnus
Haapsalu Kunstikool
Haapsalu Raamat
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

I have searched that error, but no result, haven't found nothing similar.

Comment: Where do you declare `AsukohaArray`?

Comment: That declaration would be helpful, as you seem to get the error, while traversing that array.

Comment: I think your problem is about (val.name), it should be a string but it is not, that is why all this methods are undefined. Can you do alert or console.log to see what (val.name) looks like ? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your "val" (item from the array) a primitive data type, or is it an object containing the attribute "name"?
If your val is let's say a String type, you should "search" directly into it.
Your error suggests that "val" does not contain an attribute called "name".

Also, since you are using a RegExp, there, you should probably go with

```
if( val.match(myExp) > 0 )
```

or even better, if you only care about a boolean result,

```
if ( val.test(myExp) )
```

If I am wrong, and your .name attribute exists, if it's a string, just use it directly without the parenthesis:

```
if( val.name.test(myExp) )
```

Comment: what is test in this case?

Comment: Test is a way of searching something within a string using regular expressions. If that something is found, "test" returns true, otherwise, false. Test is a method of the String primitive. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: val.name.test is not a function  im getting this error

Comment: This most likely means "name" is not a string. Have you also tried val.test(RegExp) ? Also, you can try to access name as a string by doing val.name.toString().test(RegExp).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: val.name.toString(...).test is not a function  that error now, so you want to say, my name object is not a string?

Comment: when i check typeof then javascript is showing "true", this means AsukohaArray[0].name is a string

Comment: Tnx for the help m8 , i used String() instead of .toString()

Comment: No problem. I had to run there, but casting into string using String() is what i just tested too and then saw you figured it out. I'm glad you got it fixed. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
   if(val.indexOf(myExp) != -1){
```

instead of

```
   if(val.search(myExp) != -1){
```

Comment: it shows me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined then.

Comment: do you have this in the `<head>` :  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I think your problem is about `(val.name)`, it should be a string but it is not, that is why all this methods are undefined. Can you do `alert` or `console.log` to see what `(val.name)` looks like ?

Comment: examples:
Haapsalu piiskopilinnus,
Haapsalu Kunstikool,
Haapsalu Raamat
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

it shows this when i type in Haapsalu, that script found something but that give error to in the end

Comment: Your array is just an array of strings? Then what should the `name` property point to ...

Comment: @Sirko exactly, why `.name` ?

Comment: my array is a object array

Comment: @erkaner was just referring to OP as he answered here and not in question comments.